# Requiring a file from a required file in Sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sprockets, middleman

I would like to require a javascript file that itself requires other javascript files:

*In main.js*

```
//= require plugins

... Shared Code
```

*In plugins.js*

```
//= require vendor/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js
//= require vendor/jquery.animate-colors-min.js
//= require vendor/spin.min.js
```

However although sprockets adds the contents of plugins.js to main.js, it doesn't seem to evaluate the requires within it, so they are included as comments in the compiled main.js rather than it pulling in the js files and including them.

*In the compiled main.js*

```
//= require vendor/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js
//= require vendor/jquery.animate-colors-min.js
//= require vendor/spin.min.js

...Shared Code
```

If I add these requires into main.js rather than plugins.js, they are propprly required and their contents is included in the compiled main.js

So why isn't sprockets evaluating the includes in plugins.js?

Comment: @ShamirK Thanks. You were bang on the money. There was a utility function above them. If you add this comment as an answer I will accept. Might save someone some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place your `//=` directives at the top of plugins.js

Comment: @DaveClemmer, actually it *did* answer the question. See comment above.